# What is .j file? and how do I get .java file from .j file?

Tags: java, decompiler

I am using an assembler to convert java files to class files but when I run the assembler it only accepts .j files not .java files

Comment: Does the documentation for the tool you're using have any advice for you?

Comment: This does not make any sense to me. To "convert" java files to class file, you'd need a **compiler**. If you wanted to do that the other way round, you needed a **decompiler**. An **assembler** doesn't really fit in here.

Comment: This is the link to the documentation: https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau
https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau/blob/master/README.TXT

Comment: Ah, that makes it clear.

Comment: [This](http://www.reviversoft.com/file-extensions/j) link has some details about .j file.

Answer (score 2):

.j files are descriptions of Java classes, written in a simple assembler-like syntax using the Java Virtual Machine instruction set  and Jasmin assembler converts them into binary Java class files, suitable for loading by a Java runtime system.

So for your question . You have to get different compiler to compile java applications.

Answer (score 2):

> Q: What is .j file?

You say that you are using the Krakatau Bytecode Tools ...

A ".j" file is a file containing Krakatua's of JVM bytecode assembly language.  This is a human-readable representation of bytecodes that can be turned back into a ".class" file using the Krakatua assembler.

The documentation that you linked to says this about Krakatua assembly language:

> *"The Krakatau assembler uses a syntax similar to Jasmin, but with 
>   many new features, most importantly the ability to directly specify
>   constant poolreferences. For more information about the syntax look 
>   in the Documentation folder."*

---

> Q: How do I get .java file from .j file?

You should first assemble the ".j" file to a ".class" file, and then decompile the ".class" file to a ".java" file.

Note that you will not be able to recover the original Java source code, and you may find that the decompiled ".java" file you get by this procedure is:

- not valid (i.e. compilable) Java source code, or
- not a correct translation of the ".j" file / ".class" file into Java.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there also a way to get .j file from .java file?

Comment: @Razieh Compile ".java" to ".class" using standard Java compiler, then disassemble ".class" to ".j".

Comment: My intention is to edit a single class file from a jar file(with many classes). That's why I used this assembler! But I did not know that it won't give me an option to edit java file but the bytecode file and it is not easy for me to manipulate the bytecode file. To convert j file to java, so I can edit java file and then recompile it to class using a standard java compiler is not possible for me, since I don't want to recompile the whole project but only a single java file (without the main function) so compiler gives me sysntax errors. do you have any other solutions?

Comment: If you are going to edit ".class" files, you really need to learn and understand the bytecode instruction set.